# Json megamenu with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to get the markup/nesting correct with jQuery.

I have a json feed which im making a megamenu with.
Example layout im trying to replicate.

```
<ul>
   <li class="top-level"><a href="">Home</a></li>
   <li class="top-level"><a href="">Find your holiday</a>
        <ul class="heading">
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Destinations</a></li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Latest ski deals</a></li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Where to stay</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Snippet from the JSON

```
{
    "navigation": [
            {
                    "title": "Home",
                    "link": ""
 },
            {
                    "title": "Find your ski holiday",
                    "link": "#URLhere",
                    "headingArray": [
                            {
                                    "heading": [
                                            {
                                                    "title": "Destinations",
                                                    "link": "#URLhere",
                                                    "subheading": [
                                                            {
                                                                    "title": "Andorra",
                                                                    "link": "#URLhere"
},
                                                            {
                                                                    "title": "Austria",
                                                                    "link": "#URLhere"
},
```

Here's the jsfiddle i've been working on http://jsfiddle.net/imshuffling/wC9VG/7/

I'm having problems wrapping jquery in html with the correct nesting, any help would be great.

**UPDATE**
Apologies if i wasn't clear before.
I have got the items appearing in the correct order, can anyone help with the wrapping      elements, still having some trouble with this.

```
 <li class="top-level"><a href="">Find your holiday</a>
        <ul class="heading">
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Destinations</a></li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Latest ski deals</a></li>
            <li class="heading"><a href="">Where to stay</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
```

updated http://jsfiddle.net/imshuffling/wC9VG/12/

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: This thing screems for recursion. Is the json structure cut in stone, or can we make suggestions to improve it?

Comment: Improvements would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Whats your question about..?

Comment: I'm trying to get the correct html structure in jQuery. Having some issues wrapping <ul> around elements. @Imperative spoke about the possible need for recursion, I'm not familiar with this..

Comment: Ok so what advantage will you get serialising the menu as JSon rather than HTML ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil Currently there is no CMS on the site, we have backend and front end devs working on it. so it has been decided (above me) that we will get a json feed for the main menu structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the way you iterate the objects/arrays, making heavy use of $.each. But as you requested, modified code which outputs the desired html. Just added the necessary `<ul>` tags and changed the whole thing to string concatination for performance and stuff ..

http://jsfiddle.net/wC9VG/13/

```
$(function () {
    var nav = $('#nav'),
        html = '';

    $.each(json.navigation, function (idx, obj) {
        console.log(obj);

        if (this.headingArray) {
            $.each(this.headingArray, function () {
                html+='<ul class="heading">';
                $.each(this.heading, function () {
                    html+='<li class="heading"><a href="' + this.link + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>';

                    $.each(this.subheading, function () {
                        html+='<li class="subheading"><a href="' + this.link + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>';
                    });
                });
                html+='</ul>';
            });
        } else {
            html += '<li class="top-level"><a href="' + obj.link + '">' + obj.title + '</a></li>';
        }

    });

    nav.html(html);
});
```

Comment: thanks again much appreciated, what would you suggest? Would you do anything to the JSON structure? Cheers